# Regular Expression for No Apostrophes or Ampersands

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I was hoping someone could help me out in coming up with a regular expression that I need for a form input. Here is what I can and cannot accept:

> - No apostrophe
> - No ampersand
> - No blank value
> - Everything else is fair game as far as I know

EDIT:

checkRegexp function:

```
function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: It's probably a good idea to ask what is the reason for not accepting these values? From that simple request, it sounds a *lot* like a very poor attempt at filtering input to avoid attacks. Trust me when I say that if the aim is to be secure, this is not the right place to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this one: `/^[^'&]+$/`

```js
var test = [
    "&test",
    "'aaa",
    "WHIte Space",
    "RegexIsAwesome",
    "          ",
];

test.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element + " => " + /^[^'&]+$/.test(element.trim()));
});
```

Comment: I think spaces are allowed! He said no blank values not spaces!

Comment: Yes, that is correct @ibrahimmahrir the "WHIte Space" should turn out true

Comment: Both of these answers work...also, something i just thought of....is there a way so that if you only entered a blank space and no actual characters it would return false?

Comment: @Rataiczak24 just call `trim()`

Comment: This is my current line of code for the regex...`valid = valid && checkRegexp( sku_group, /^[^'&]+$/, "Please enter a valid SKU Group name" );` Would I need to add something to the function i have above it in order to use `trim()`?

Comment: what does `checkRegexp` do? @Rataiczak24

Comment: i added the function in my posting

Comment: @Rataiczak24 change it to `regexp.test( o.val().trim() )` and use real names next time for your variables

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
/^[^'&]+$/
```

Try and learn regex at [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com).

Comment: Both of these answers work...also, something i just thought of....is there a way so that if you only entered a blank space and no actual characters, it would return false?

Comment: `/^[^'&]*[^'&\s][^'&]*$/`